# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config

Tags: spring-boot

*i can't understand ther Error ,what should i do? 
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension*

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.registerBeansForRoot(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:169)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.registerIfNotAlreadyRegistered(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

The method's class, org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/HCL/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/HCL/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension
```

*i added latest versions of dependencies eventhough it will showing again*

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/jta -->

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.15.2</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

*Please Help!*

Comment: My guess is that you're using different versions of some spring-boot dependencies. You should probably post your `pom.xml` if you need more detailed help

Comment: please check , i posted my pom.xml

Answer (score 5):

You should not mention version for your `spring-data-jpa`. Spring-boot parent dependency will resolve that automatically.

Instead of this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <! -- <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>  comment or remove this line -->
</dependency>
```

Update:
You are using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.2.4` and different `spring-data-jpa` version, that's why getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spring-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-jdbc you should use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following steps refering STS:

1. adjust the correct dependencies in build.graddle
2. erase the cache directory ( normally in 'C:\Users\your-name\ .gradle\caches' )
3. clean de Project ( Main menu > Project > Clean... )
4. right click in the main java in Run as > Spring Boot App
   or
5. right click in name of project in Project Explorer > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project

then the errors will disappear!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the given dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version> <!- use latest version -->
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The issue is happening because you have conflicting versions of same class due to incompatible versions of dependencies available in pom. So, remove explicit version declaration from your pom and let maven resolve the dependencies from the managed versions of the parent pom.