# Removing exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class} throws an error

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, oracle11g

I am working on an automation suite built on Spring boot. I was using `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` to disable the database related stuffs for my application, but now for the validation part I need to add database. When I remove exclude part, it throws me the below error. Can you please guide me what is the root cuase of this and probable solution? I'm using oracle and I used this in my application.yml as well

```
spring:
  initialize-schema: always
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1527:abcd
    username: APP_USER
    password: abc23
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Error logs -

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.detect(AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.java:36)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.findAnnotationOnBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.6.3/spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/org/springframework/boot/sql/init/dependency/AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.10/spring-beans-5.3.10.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory: file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.10/spring-beans-5.3.10.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector and org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory

2022-02-17 18:08:47.497 ERROR 27516 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@2a4a95c4] to prepare test instance [com.OfferListTests@598f6c93]

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.findAnnotationOnBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.detect(AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.java:36) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer$DependsOnDatabaseInitializationPostProcessor.detectDependsOnInitializationBeanNames(DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer.java:148) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer$DependsOnDatabaseInitializationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer.java:111) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:191) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0-M3.jar:3.0.0-M3]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0-M3.jar:3.0.0-M3]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-3.0.0-M3.jar:3.0.0-M3]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-3.0.0-M3.jar:3.0.0-M3]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-3.0.0-M3.jar:3.0.0-M3]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-3.0.0-M3.jar:3.0.0-M3]

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.49 s <<< FAILURE! -
```

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59884437/correct-the-classpath-of-your-application-so-that-it-contains-a-single-compatib

Comment: I'm getting this error - Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector and org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory - The answer has some different message. I tried those, but no answers worked for me.

Comment: Judging from this your dependencies are a bit messy. Spring Boot 2.6.3 uses Spring 5.3.15, you have 5.3.10 on your classpath for some reason. Figure out what is pulling in that conflicting version (and you might even have more conflicting dependencies).

Comment: I messed up the version by doing copy-paste. I corrected the pom and it is working now.